# conditional expectation of stochastic integral

Tags: itos-lemma, stochastic, wienerprocess, integral

let $M_t$ be the following stochastic integral

$$
M_t = \int_0^t \sigma_s dW_s  
$$

where $\sigma_t$ is a sufficiently regular deterministic function and $W_t$ is a standard Wiener process (that is $W_t \sim \mathcal{N}(0,t)$ with independent increments).

It can be shown that $M_t$ is martingale with distribution $M_t \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \Sigma_t)$ where (Ito's isometry) I have defined the variance

$$
\Sigma_t = \int_0^t \sigma^2_s ds
$$

Could you kindly check if the following two preliminary assertions are true (everywhere $0 \leq s<t<T$):

1. $M_t$ has independent increments, that is $M_s$ is independent from $M_t - M_s$.
2. Covariance: ${\mathbb E}[M_t M_s] = \Sigma_s$.

Proof of 2.: If 1. holds, reasoning as in the Wiener case:
\begin{align}
{\mathbb E}[M_t M_s] &= {\mathbb E}[(M_t - M_s + M_s )M_s] \\
&= {\mathbb E}[(M_t - M_s)M_s] + {\mathbb E}[M^2_s] \\
&= {\mathbb E}[M_t - M_s] \cdot {\mathbb E}[M_s] + {\mathbb E}[M^2_s] \\
&= {\mathbb E}[M^2_s] \\
&= \Sigma_s
\end{align}

Finally, my question: Conditional expectation: $${\mathbb E}[M_t|W_T] = ?$$

*Edit* I’m aware of the result ${\mathbb E}[W_t|W_T]=\frac{t}{T}W_T$ using brownian bridge.

Thanks for your kind attention.

*Edit2* This question has a follow-up which might be of interest as well: [Regression of stochastic integral on Wiener process](https://quant.stackexchange.com/q/62011/13528)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What a great question! I've had a go at it below, I'd say I'm about 75% sure of the result I've got to but I'd love feedback from others.

I'm going to use [the definition of the Ito integral](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/57279/ito-integral-of-functions-of-brownian-motion/57281#57281),
\begin{align}
\int^t_0 \sigma_s dW_s = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^n \sigma_{t_{i-1}} \bigl( W_{t_i} - W_{t_{i-1}} \bigr)
\end{align}
where $t_n = t$.

Then, using the expression for Brownian Bridging that you've provided above (and neglecting the $\lim_{n \to \infty}$ below for breviety)
\begin{align}
{\mathbb E}\bigl[M_t | W_T\bigr] &= {\mathbb E}\bigl[ \int^t_0 \sigma_s dW_s | W_T\bigr] \\
&= {\mathbb E}\bigl[ \ \sum_{i=1}^n \sigma_{t_{i-1}} \bigl( W_{t_i} - W_{t_{i-1}} \bigr) \ | W_T\bigr] \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n \sigma_{t_{i-1}} {\mathbb E}\bigl[ \bigl( W_{t_i} - W_{t_{i-1}} \bigr) | W_T\bigr] \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n \sigma_{t_{i-1}} \bigl( {\mathbb E}\bigl[ W_{t_i}| W_T\bigr] - {\mathbb E}\bigl[ W_{t_{i-1}} | W_T\bigr] \bigr) \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n \sigma_{t_{i-1}} \bigl( {\frac {t_i} T}W_T - {\frac {t_{i-1}} T}W_T \bigr)\\
&= {\frac {W_T} T} \sum_{i=1}^n \sigma_{t_{i-1}} \bigl( {t_i} - {t_{i-1}} \bigr) \\
&=  {\frac {W_T} T} \int_0^t \sigma_{s} ds\\
\end{align}

As a sanity check, we can see that setting $\sigma_s = 1$ reproduces the brownian bridging expression.

Comment: Good answer, StackG. I just wanted to point out that in your definition of Stochastic integral: either the sum out to run from $i=1$ to $n$, or it can run from $i=0$ to $n-1$ and then you'd need to change the indexes to $\sigma_{i+1}$ and $\left(W_{t_{i+1}}-W_{t_i}\right)$ (i.e. you cannot have the sum running from zero and then have indexes $t_{i-1}$)

Comment: Many thanks @Jan Stuller once again for the good feedback, I've now fixed this

Comment: Sorry to be picky, but the same is also true for all the sums in the Brownian Bridge :) (I am just pointing it out, because I revised Ito Integrals recently, and only once I started paying attention to the index in the sum of the definition, I started appreciating that the integrator is "forward looking": this is particularly interesting / important in the case of $$\int_0^tW_hdW_h=\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{i=1}^nW_{i-1}(W_i-W_{i-1})$$ Not writing out the indexes properly can be confusing to some readers! :)

Comment: Yes agreed, serves me right for trying to fix on my phone. Will fix the rest later!

Answer (score 4):

Just wanted to add to @StackG's great answer using a different approach. Please, double-check my solution as well because I'm not 100% sure.

Let $\sigma_t$ be sufficiently regular such that $\dot{\sigma}_t \stackrel{def}{=}\frac{d \sigma}{dt}$ is well defined. Then, Ito's lemma:

$$
d(\sigma_t W_t) = \dot{\sigma}_t W_t dt + \sigma_t dW_t
$$

which in integral form reads

$$
\sigma_t W_t = \int^t_0 \dot{\sigma}_s W_s ds + \int^t_0 \sigma_s dW_s
$$

We have then the representation

\begin{align}
M_t & \stackrel{def}{=}   \int^t_0 \sigma_s dW_s \\
    &= \sigma_t W_t - \int^t_0 \dot{\sigma}_s W_s ds 
\end{align}

Therefore, using Fubini to interchange integral with expectation, recalling that $\sigma_t$ is deterministic, and that ${\mathbb E}[W_t|W_T] = \frac{t}{T} W_T$ we can write the requested conditional expectation as

\begin{align}
{\mathbb E}[M_t|W_T] & \stackrel{def}{=}  {\mathbb E}\left[\int^t_0 \sigma_s dW_s \bigg| W_T  \right] \\
                     &= \sigma_t {\mathbb E}[W_t|W_T] - \int^t_0 \dot{\sigma}_s {\mathbb E}[W_s|W_T]  ds \\
                     &= \sigma_t \frac{t}{T} W_T - \frac{W_T}{T} \int^t_0 \dot{\sigma}_s s ds \\
                    &= \sigma_t \frac{t}{T} W_T - \frac{W_T}{T} \left[ \sigma_t t - \int^t_0 \sigma_s \cdot 1 ds\right] \\
                    &= \frac{W_T}{T} \int^t_0 \sigma_s ds 
\end{align}
where integration by parts has been used in the next-to-last line.

Comment: Nice solution @Gabriele Pompa!

Comment: Apparently one cannot accept more than one answer. I’m accepting yours, as it seems to attract more consensus. Thanks!